# Proxy forward API to server without CORS

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I'm inexperienced.

I've built a simple app using Angularjs that does some basic XHR calls to a server that doesn't have CORS. I can get around this problem by running a nodejs+express server that proxys the call.

Is there a similar solution for a firebase hosted app or will I need to look elsewhere?

Comment: You need CORS for firebase based app?

Comment: No. That's not my question.

Comment: Can you rephrase then? It's unclear of what you're asking.

Comment: What code/data are you looking to put on Firebase? Keep in mind that Firebase is 15 products, so it helps to be specific about which of these you are trying to use.

Comment: Thanks - I'll try and rephrase.

I need to retrieve some json data via an API that doesn't support CORS. A common workaround is to use nodeJS and Express to proxy the data so all code is retrieved via server-side calls only. 

I am wondering if there is a solution using a Firebase hosted app that will allow me to retrieve data via the API without encountering a CORS denial.

Comment: Do you mean using Firebase hosting product? Also you should check if the API supports `JSONP`. It's a JSON object wrapped in javascript function call.

Comment: Yes, Firebase hosting. I'm afraid I can't use jsonp either, as the API relies on a client key and secret and these would need to be hidden server side.